# access make list field visible when clicking Button

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

In an access form, I try to make a list field visible when the fokus is on another textfield in which new data should be filled in. The backround is that one should know the last data inputs to create a new one.
As a first step I tried to make the list (liste91) visible when clicking on a button, but I failed using the following code.

```
Private Sub Befehl97_Click()
    Forms!projects!liste91.SetFocus
    Me.liste91.visible = True
End Sub
```

I get error in the line Me.list91
what is wrong?
thank you for your help!

Comment: do you have `liste91` as a control in two different forms?

Comment: no, I have only one form (projects). In this form I created a list without connection, just to show, just to know what is in. In the same form I want to fill new data in (text field) e.g project catagories. When I enter the text field the list should get visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set focus to something not yet visible. Just switch the order:

```
Private Sub Befehl97_Click()
    Me.liste91.visible = True
    Me.liste91.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: with "me." it doesnt work. but forms! projects! list91.visible=true its fine. Thank you!